# RegEx to find all occurrence of some character with exclusion of certain part of text

Tags: regex

I’m trying to write a regex to find all occurrence of **'** character but exclude these parts of text that begin with [ or < and end with ] or >.

Here is an exemplary text:

```
This is some text with ' character to find and [text to 'exclude' with letters and numbers 0-9 '' ] and another part of text with 'more characters' to find <and 'more to' exclude> and again some text with 'character' to find
```

I tried regex with negative lookahead:

```
(?!((\[|<)[\s\S]*?(\]|>)))'
```

but it didn’t work.

After several hours I’m run out of ideas :(. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A very helpful site is regexlib (http://www.regexlib.com) they have a large library of Regular Expressions. They also have a RegEx tester. Also Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is a very useful RegEx tool.

Comment: @BillW: I will not advise this site (regexlib.com) and this kind of sites in general since they are full of stupid patterns. The goal is to understand how to write a regex pattern, not to copy/paste a regex pattern without understanding what it means.

Comment: @anubhava: PHP language

Comment: ok then @Jan's answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either use

```
\[.*?\]|<.*?>|(')
```

And use the captured groups (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/leZBeL/1)) or use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` version if your engine (PHP, Perl, PCRE in general, ...) supports it:

```
(?:\[.*?\]|<.*?>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'
```

See [**a demo for the latter here**](https://regex101.com/r/leZBeL/2).

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks a lot Jan :).